# mpi4py: trouble sending messages to slaves via send/recv

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to run the following code on a slurm cluster. The logic is simple: The master node sends items of a list to the slave node for printing. It finally uses a message with tag=1 to tell the slave to terminate the loop.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
status = MPI.Status()


if rank == 0:
    data = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
    for k in data:
        comm.send(k, dest=1, tag=11)
    comm.send('', dest=1, tag=1)
elif rank == 1:
    while True:
        print('trying to get something')
        item = comm.recv(source=0,status=status)

        if status.tag == 1:
            print('terminating')
            break

        print(item)
```

I'm getting this output on my local machine which is expected:

```
trying to get something
string1
trying to get something
string2
trying to get something
string3
trying to get something
terminating
```

But on the cluster, it shows me the following output and it seems that the slave gets blocked during the first comm.recv indefinitely.

```
 trying to get something
```

I appreciate any ideas about the flaws in the logic for termination of the slave or solving the mentioned problem.

Comment: have you tried to run both simple `MPI` and `mpi4py` helloworld program ?

Comment: I have run them and they work fine. The odd thing is that when I use that while True, the program hangs on the cluster until it hits the wall time. Really confusing matter!

Comment: do your helloworld MPI program make any communication ? if not, you might want to try a simple ring program. what if you print the tag right after the `MPI_Recv()` ?

Comment: The program never reaches the line after item= ... .when I add a print line there not even once. This behavior is really confusing and I'm just about to assume that there might be a bug in the library version used by the slurm cluster.

Answer (score -1):

The only reason I can see is that the tag of the recv does not match any tags and then recv do not return. But I was thinking that the default tag is indeed MPI.ANY_TAG, maybe not.
Try to add: tag=MPI.ANY_TAG in your recv
If it does not work, try your code without the tags. Then try to fix the tag version.

But you might be surprised on the results... Might be that the first message that recv take is the one with the tag=1, and therefor break the while. It will probably not be a safe code at all.

If you want to do: get a arbitrary number of message from a given sender it would be better to used non-blocking communications.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024214/mpi-buffered-send-receive-order?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) the order of messages sent is guaranteed to be preserved and the default tag is MPI.ANY_TAG. The code works fine locally but just gets stuck on the cluster.

Comment: If the implementation respect the standard :-(, not always the case :-(.
I think the default is -1, maybe on the cluster MPI_ANY_TAG is not set to -1.